# SPO: Document Library for custom page layout is not working ( error on Page creation)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, page-layout

I am getting error while creating page using custom page layout, in a document library

Below are the steps followed :

1. Created a custom page layout
2. Created a document library & added the content type of page layout

[image]

3. Error while creating page

[image]

After providing page name and submitting

[image]

Any reason for this error ?

Is this possible, to create page in a document library ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything update? Similar issue post:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/ebf8145f-4aab-46e1-a6e8-ff706a16d949/document-library-for-custom-page-layout-is-not-working-error-on-page-creation?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

Comment: Haven't found any solution yet. ** And as per reply on the post above, its not possible due to limitation of SharePoint.**